# How should I authenticate API users in my client-server system?

Tags: api, rest, client-server

I am writing an API to use with my mobile app. I want to use Api Key authentication.

In this kind of system, should I give an api key to each user? Or should I only give Api Key per application that connects to the API?

The reason that I asked that is:

If I give every user api key and authenticate them by their api key, authenticated user will be only one, and I can make requests like /reviews/ and server will return all reviews which are done by authenticated user.

On the other hand, the app will authenticate to use the api, and I should make request like "/reviews?userId=23842374283423".

Which one is the most used type of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the API keys are issued to the developer who consumes the API rather than the application. Although in most cases each key is used only for one application, in theory you could have another one using the same key. I would recommend going for the second approach.